# Shell Script to rename file with string from another filename

Tags: bash, shell, unix, scripting, rename

I have been stuck with a task where I need to rename a file with a substring from another filename and then move it to a directory.

What I want to achieve here is as below
I have a file named dummy.txt and another file named 20150416demo.xml
What I want is the file abc.txt to be renamed with the date from the xml file i.e. dummy20150416.txt
The final step is to move it to a different location. Appreciate you responses

Thanks

Comment: E.X.A.M.P.L.E.S PLEASE! Nobody is gonna understand what do you want to do.

Comment: What I want to achieve here is as below.
I have a file named abc.txt and another file named 20150416asddf.xml.
What I want is the file abc.txt to be remaed with the date from the xml file i.e. 20150416.txt then concatenate a text say qwer20150416.txt
The final move is to move it to a different location.
Hope this explanation helps.

Comment: No no no, [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29649358/edit).  That's where the details should be.

Answer (score 0):

To rename/concatenate and move according to what you want you can use this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
file="20150416demo.xml"
date=${file:0:8}
mv abc.txt /destination/path/dummy$date.txt
```